# NotReadableError when calling getUserMedia for desktopCapture in iframe in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Our webapp make use of screensharing. We've created Chrome extension that prompts user to select a screen/window to share which it then passes as `sourceId` to webapp script:

```
navigator.getUserMedia(
  video: {
    mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
      chromeMediaSourceId: sourceId,
    },
    optional: [],
  },
  audio: false,
}, handleSuccess, handleError);
```

It works until our webapp is embedded into `iframe`. In that case `getUserMedia` calls `handleError` with `NotReadableError`.

Both pages (ebmedding (`acme.com`) and embedded (`example.com`)) are served from https.

Some relevant info from extension's manifest:

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "js": [ "content-script.js" ],
    "run_at": "document_idle",
    "matches": ["https://*.example.com/*"],
    "all_frames": true
  }
],
"permissions": [
  "desktopCapture",
  "https://*.example.com/"
],
...
```

Is there a way to make it working also for embedded webapp?

Comment: I guess the permissions aren't transferrable across origins.

Comment: @wOxxOm adding `https://*/*` (or `https://acme.com/`) to `permissions` did not help.

Comment: It is embedded webapp who asked extension for screen stream and it also consumed returned `streamId` in `getUserMedia`. There is no JS code involved from hosting webpage and so its origin should not be used anywhere. Or do you think that the origin of media stream is always set to top frame?

Comment: "if the app runs in an iframe and asks the media permissions then I would expect the browser to allow subsequent use of streamId only in the origin of the app (the iframe)" --- This is exactly the case, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Quoting the docs: "The stream can only be used by frames in the given tab whose security origin matches tab.url."

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for reading the docs for us :-). Unfortunately it seems to mean that what we need is actually impossible :-/.

Comment: @wOxxOm - this is description from docs related to 'tab' in my case i pass only 'screen' to 'chooseDesktopMedia' and in my case is still throw error on getUserMedia when i request it from subdomain https iframe... In addition, this scenario works well in FF, so it seems like chromium bug.

Comment: @OlegYudovich, the issue you've encountered seems different despite the same error message. You can check https://crbug.com for an existing report or submit a new one.

Comment: I opened bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=763846&can=2&q=GetUserMedia%20iframe&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified